# In method call args, how to override keyword argument of unpacked dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I'm trying to use template keyword args for convenience in a function call (via dict and keyword arguments) whilst being able to override some arguments.

For example, if we start with a module mymod containing the line `template_kvps = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}`

I can just:

```
import mymod

def func(**kwargs):
    pass

func(**mymod.template_kvps)
```

then I can access my `template_kvps` within `func()`. But I want to be able to pass a different value for `a` with minimal overhead.

All I can think of is to alter the dictionary before the function call: `kvps = {**template_kvps, 'a': 3}; func(**kvps)`, but that's twice the number of lines and I'm using this function several times in each of around 1000 test scripts.

I'd ideally like to redefine `func` so that I can do sth like `func(**mymod.template_kvps, a=3)` but as it is, Python errors with something about repeated parameters.

btw I'm happy to consider changing the format of the `template_kvps`.

**EDIT** (will move to answer at some point) I could use a wrapper method instead

```
def func_template(a=1, b=2):
    func(a, b)

func_template(a=3)
```

Comment: I wonder why we're all pulling our hairs over one extra line of code. I don't see how that's a mess.

Comment: How does `func(mymod.template_kvps)` work? Shouldn't it be `func(**mymod.template_kvps)`?

Comment: @Artyer, yes, my mistake, corrected

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the built-in `dict` type for that purpose. It accepts another dict as argument and additional key-value pairs as keyword arguments (which have precedence over the values in the other dict).

Thus you can create an updated dictionary via `dict(template_vars, a=1)`.

You can unfold this dict as keyword arguments: `func(**dict(...))`.

Like that there is no need to change the signature of your function and you can update/add as many key-value pairs as you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
func(**{**mymod.template_kvps, 'a': 3})
```

But this might not be obvious at first glance, but is as obvious as what you were doing before.

What I would suggest is having multiple templates (e.g. `template_kvps_without_a`), but this would depend on your specific use case:

```
func(**mymod.template_kvps_without_a, a=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider function decorators as this keeps the syntax mostly the same as you requested. The implementation would look something like:

```
def combine(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    fargs = {}
    if args and isinstance( args[0], dict ):
      fargs = args[0].copy()
    fargs.update(kwargs)
    return func(**fargs)
  return wrapper


@combine
def funky(**kwargs):
  for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
    print "%s: %s" % (k, v)

# All of these work as expected
funky( {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, a=3 )
funky( {'a': 1, 'b': 2} )
funky( a=3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that updates any values you want changed. (Edited so that original dictionary is not modified.)

```
import mymod

def replace(dict1, dict2):
  ans = dict1.copy()
  ans.update(dict2)
  return ans

def func(**kwargs):
  pass

func(replace(mymod.template_kvps, {'a':3}))
```

Comment: Thanks, much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
func(a=3, **{key: value for key, value in mymod.template_kvps.items() if key != 'a')})
```

However I'd suggest to write another line of code, and not confuscating it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the template argument to be a positional argument, with the keys to be overwritten as `**kwargs`.

```
def func(template_dict, **kwargs):
    updated_dict = {**template_dict, **kwargs}
    return updated_dict

print(func({'a':1, 'b':2}, a=3)) # {'a': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Note that the double-unpacking syntax requires Python 3.5+. On older versions, use:

```
updated_dict = template_dict.copy()
updated_dict.update(kwargs)
```